# Transform number in string to alphabetics number

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm looking to do convert numbers from strings like "1,86" to alphebitcs numbers like "one point eighty six".

I'm using `nodeJS` and `Cherrio` for my webscraping.

Does anyone know how could I do that ?

Comment: Google and npmjs.com is your friend https://www.npmjs.com/package/number-to-words

Comment: Numbers after the decimal point are spoken separately. 1.86 = One point eight six. 2.7543 = Two point seven five four three.